# Within a VSCode extension is it possible to have a panel that switches between a webview and tree view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i want to add a new explorer panel into vscode. I want it to display either a treeView or a webView depending on if the user has connected to my backend application. I can see something similar in the base of vscode in the folder view. When no folder is open this view is shown

[image: Folder view no folder open]

and when you have a folder open it looks like

[image: Folder view with folder open]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who finds this question, the behaviour seen in the file explorer is achievable through a [Welcome Message](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#welcome-content).

A view's welcome message will show when the tree for that view is empty.

## Preview

### Welcome Message

[image: welcome-message]

### Normal tree view

[image: tree-view]

## Example

In your `package.json`, declare:

- The view
- The view welcome message
- The command which the welcome message button should execute

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "myExtension.myCommand",
            "title": "My Custom Command"
        }
    ],
    "views": {
        "explorer": [
            {
                "id": "myCustomView",
                "name": "My Custom View",
                "contextualTitle": "My Custom View"
            }
        ]
    },
    "viewsWelcome": [
        {
            "view": "myCustomView",
            "contents": "Welcome to my custom view! [learn more](https://google.com/).\n[Get Started](command:myExtension.myCommand)"
        }
    ]
}
```

In your `extension.ts`

- Define the button command
- Hook up the view to the view provider

```typescript
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { CustomViewProvider } from './CustomViewProvider';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    // Add the custom view
    const customViewProvider = new CustomViewProvider();
    vscode.window.registerTreeDataProvider('myCustomView', customViewProvider);


    // Add the command
    let myCustomCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.myCommand', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('This is my custom command!');
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(myCustomCommand);
}

export function deactivate() { }
```

In `CustomViewProvider.ts`, define when your view is empty or not.

```typescript
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export class CustomViewProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<vscode.TreeItem> {
    getTreeItem(element: vscode.TreeItem): vscode.TreeItem {
        return element;
    }

    getChildren(element?: vscode.TreeItem): Thenable<vscode.TreeItem[]> {
        // NOTE:
        //      When TRUE, the welcome message will show
        //      When FALSE, the welcome message will NOT show
        var showEmptyView = true;

        if (showEmptyView) {
            return Promise.resolve([]);
        }

        return Promise.resolve([
            new vscode.TreeItem('This view is not empty!')
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of VS Code 1.25, views may only contain tree views. Support for showing a webview in the side bar is tracked by https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46585

If all you need is a button or simple prompt, you can use a tree view with a single node in the first case

Comment: I need more than just a button the image shown was just am example of where in vscode the behavior that i want already exists, i just don't know how to do it in an extension but can see how the base code works. It seems silly that the base code can do it but not an extension